# How can you insert a row of data into a table valued function

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've used a very simplified version of a function I have. It does everything I want it to, I just need to be able to add a placeholder row when a certain value shows up. In case you're wondering why I'd create a function for the SELECT statement below

Let's say I have this function

```
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[FN_TestFunction] (@FragnetID INT)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
    RETURN
        SELECT * 
        FROM dbo.TestTable
        WHERE FragnetID = @FragnetID
```

and it returned this

| Activity | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 12345 | Start |
| 12346 | Middle |
| 12347 | Finish |

But I wanted it to do this.

| Activity | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 12345 | Start |
| 12346 | Middle |
|  | Inspections |
| 12347 | Finish |

So immediately after Middle, I want a row to say "Inspections" on the name. It should always say the word "Inspections" and all the other fields can be empty.

How can I do this? Is this even possible?

Comment: You can use `UNION` to return the extra row in the function. However, the ordering of the rows depending on the the `ORDER BY` clause in the select query on the function

Comment: Is the function always going to return a row with the name `Middle` and never return its own row with the name `Inspections` regardless of the input?

Comment: so, you mean to say that if `middle` is present, you want to add one more row, with data as `inspection` ?

Comment: @VenkataramanR yes that's correct

Comment: @AaronBertrand sometimes it will, sometimes it won't

Comment: Then you should explain what should happen when it does, and what should happen when it doesn't/

Answer (score 1):

Below select query will bring the desired result. Here it should be your table valued function instead of the table variable.

```
declare @tbl table(activity varchar(20),name varchar(20))

insert into @tbl
values(12345,'Start'),(12346,'Middle'),(12347,'Finish')

select * 
from
@tbl
union
select case when lag(name,1,name)over(order by name) = 'Middle' 
then
'' else  activity end activity,
case when lag(name,1,name)over(order by name) = 'Middle' 
then 'Inspections' else name end [name]
from
@tbl
order by name desc
```

Comment: I can't do an insert into, the data won't be set like in this example, it'll be coming from other tables with several joins in between them

Comment: @profiter the insert is just to build a table variable with dummy data, to demonstrate selecting from _somewhere_, since [you didn't supply one](https://sqlblog.org/fiddle).